# How to create Connection class

Tags: java

This is a code i tried for common Connection class jdbc project but it returns only null

```
package dbDemo;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

     public class ConnectionDemo {
     Connection con;
          public Connection getConnection() {

                 try
                 {
                     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");    
                     String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myserver";
                     String name="root";
                     String pwd="admin123";

                     con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,name,pwd);
                     }
                       catch(Exception e)
                         {
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                         }
                       return con;
                    }}
```

anybody can please help this code right or wrong.

Comment: have you install JDBC jar?

Answer (score 1):

Please change the driver class to 
`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Then you should have the `mysql-connector.jar` in your classpath.

If it is an eclipse ide just *right-click on the project->build path->configure build path->go to libraries that->add external jar->select the mysql-connector.jar* from the place you kept after downloading it.

Comment: i changed that one but got same..,my output is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
null

Comment: Add the mysql-connector.jar to the classpath like i said in the answer one more thing in place of `sysout` just use `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

Download JDBC jar from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html and make sure that you include it to Java's CLASSPATH when you run your application.

After you unpack a downloaded zip or tar file, you'll need only one file to make it working: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

After extracting the JAR file you can run your program like this:

```
java -cp path-to-mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar your-java-class
```

The suggestion about changing 'driver' to 'Driver' in the driver's class name is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to know the exact error you have to use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e.getMessage())` and then execute again it will print all the errors which help you to debug more

Comment: System.out.println(e.printStackTrace()) this is possible sir